# can't find build.gradle in Eclipse projects

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I want to add library to my android project in eclipse but I can't find **build.gradle**

[image]

I tried to install Gradle plugin in eclipse and create new Gradle project but the project is for java not for android

[image]

So, how can I create new android project with gradle in eclipse like android studio?
And how to add libraries to my project?

Comment: Just as a FYI, [eclipse has been unsupported for Android since 2015](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Comment: ... Gradle? in Eclipse?!

Comment: not all eclipse projects just android projects

Answer (score 0):

Install gradle on your computer and then open the console.

Go to your project's directory and run the task "gradle init". This will add the files that gradle needs.

To add libraries to you project, add them to the "build.gradle" file and then run "gradle build" task to download them.

PS: as referred in the comments, Eclipse isn't the advisable tool to build an Android project, you should go with [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

Comment: what is the task "gradle init" and how to run it

Comment: @Firstdev I seams you aren't very used to work with gradle as a standalone building tool so I would advise you to read their documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html). In your case you should read the [installation guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) and [how to create a new build](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/). These last two links should explain you the basics of gradle. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: But this won't help him with Eclipse at all.

Comment: @KlingKlang By using the Eclipse plugin in Gradle is possible. This [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) explains it better.